# running Jest tests with webpack configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, next.js, babeljs

I am using `next-optimized-images` package to optimize my images in my next.js project.

This is a config that's supposed to enable me to load images and resize them automatically using URL params such as `?sizes[]=300`

## What works

### next.config.js

```
const withOptimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");

module.exports = withOptimizedImages({
  optimizeImagesInDev: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png)$/i,
        loader: "responsive-loader",
        options: {
          adapter: require("responsive-loader/sharp"),
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

I am also using `png` and `jpg` optimizing libraries:

`"imagemin-mozjpeg": "^8.0.0"`,`"imagemin-optipng": "^6.0.0"`

My JSON/JS files have their images structured in a following way:

```
{
  ...,
  imgs: [
    require("../../static/img/foo/bar.jpg?sizes[]=200,sizes[]=300"),
    ...,
  ]
}
```

so that when using it with `responsive-loader` everything is loaded as it should, i.e. images' paths are replaced with an object in the app that contains two paths with different sizes.

## What does not work

What does not work, however, are the tests (jest tests) that used to work before I introduced the `require` declaration in each image array element. All it says is that it cannot import the required module because, most likely, it does not use the webpack configuration that would resolve those paths with arguments. How do I tell it to do that?

### Error message:

`Cannot find module '../../static/img/foo/bar.jpg?sizes[]=200,sizes[]=300' from 'categories.js'`

I cannot simply use paths to images and then `require` them later in `<img src={require(path)} />` tags, because they have to be relative for this library to work and I'm using those images in many different components (some are nested). With this library, the webpack configuration gets very difficult when it comes to absolute paths and also paths with arguments like `size` do not get resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. All you have to do is create a config file for jest.

In your `package.json` change `"test"` from `react-scripts test` to `jest -c jest.config.js`

### jest.config.js

```
{
  "bail": true,
  "verbose": true,

  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^.*(jpe?g|png).*$": "<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js"
  }
}
```

It's important to use `moduleNameMapper` to match against any image extension you need. Create another file named `assetsTransformer.js` which will process your required images. You don't actually have to do anything with imported images if you don't need to. In my case I did not so I just created a file with the following contents:

## assetsTransformer.js

```
module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    return;
  },
};
```